# Paragraph formatting losing first line break (Coldfusion/Oracle)

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, oracle11g, string-formatting, coldfusion-10

Using Oracle 11g, CF 10.

I'm trying to understand how and why CF/Oracle is changing saved paragraphs. If the following content is saved into a clob field, from a textarea input:

```
This is paragraph 1.
This is paragraph 2.

This is paragraph 3.
```

When output to the page, using:

```
<p>
    <cfoutput>#ParagraphFormat(myTable.myCLOBfield)#</cfoutput>
</p>
```

It is formatted like so:

```
This is paragraph 1. This is paragraph 2.

This is paragraph 3.
```

When I copy the saved filed directly from the results of a query and paste it into Notepad,
with View All Characters turned on, I can see that the formatting is the same as the original input, and that all CRLFs are where I expect to see them.

It seems like Oracle is converting the CRLFs into chr(10)s. Using

```
regexp_replace(myCLOBfield, chr(13) || chr(10), 'HEY', 1, 0) myCLOBfield
```

doesn't result in anything being replaced. However, using

```
regexp_replace(myCLOBfield, chr(10), 'HEY', 1, 0) myCLOBfield
```

does find all CRLFs and replaces them with 'HEY'. But I'm mystified why pasting the contents into Notepad then shows CRLFs and formats them properly, while ParagraphFormat loses the first line break.

It seems like the most consistent solution is to replace all double chr(10)s with singles, and then replace all single chr(10)s with doubles, so I always get a double line break, and all new paragraphs are separated by a single line. I did it like so:

```
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(myCLOBfield, chr(10) || chr(10), chr(10), 1, 0), chr(10), chr(10) || chr(10), 1, 0) myCLOBfield
```

which results in the following (acceptable) formatting:

```
This is paragraph 1.

This is paragraph 2.

This is paragraph 3.
```

Anybody have a better idea of how to retain the original formatting?

Comment: (Edit) It is not Oracle. I think you are misunderstanding the function. `ParagraphFormat` is doing exactly what it claims: [replaces a single CRLF with a space and double newline characters with HTML paragraph tags (`<p>`)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e24.html). Wrong IMO, but that is the way the function works. To replace CRLF with an html break instead, try a simple replace: `#replace(content, chr(13) & chr(10), "<br>", "all")#`

Comment: You could try to continue using paragraph format + CSS or `<pre>` tags, but I am not sure I would recommend it

Comment: @Leigh, don't know how I missed that. I agree, it's wrong. Oracle does seem to store CRLF as LF only, though -- regexp_replace doesn't pick up CRLF combinations.

Comment: @earachefl - Yeah the behavior is definitely not ... intuitive.  I have not used Oracle in a while, but I would be very surprised if it was actually modifying the value.  Try examining your test string (character-by-character). Check the ascii values of each character before and after the insert. See if the CRLF is still present. That will tell you if the data is really the problem or if it is regexp_replace.